# It's possible to build an ELS 'bucket_selector' query with bodybuilder?

Tags: elasticsearch

Using 'bodybuilder', is it possible to get a 'bucket_selector' aggregation.

I'm trying to get something like this:

```
"aggs": {
"aggname1": {
    "terms": {
        "field": "field1",
        "size": 5
    },
    "aggs": {
        "aggname2": {
            "avg": {
                "field": "field2"
            }
        },

        "a_bucker_filter": {
            "bucket_selector": {
                "buckets_path": {
                    "bucker_selector_name": "aggname2"
                },
                "script": [script]
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do here. Do you have an example?

Comment: This is the end of a query. It aggregates by a term, then it aggregates by the avg of a field, and finally has a script using the avg aggregation.